# Why isn't my defined CSS file being loaded? Where did this other file come from?

Tags: css, caching

This is a super confusing problem, but unfortunately it's tough to provide evidence for to help y'all troubleshoot.  I'm really hoping someone just ran into it before and knows the solution.

If you load this site in your browser: http://buttonspace.com

You'll notice the formatting looks terrible.  Yesterday it was fine and I haven't changed anything.

Now if you view the source, you'll see in the `<HEAD>` that the CSS file is defined as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

You can view the "supposed" contents of it here:
http://buttonspace.com/css/styles.css

Note that it starts with:

```
/* content */
.text-header {
font-size: 12pt;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

I've never seen this CSS before.  It's definitely not the CSS that I wrote.

Now, in my *real* CSS file that I can view by FTPing to the web server, it starts with:

```
* { padding:0; margin:0; outline:0; }
html, body {
background:#fff;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:18px;
color:#6d6d6d;
height:100%;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't send you a link to view yourself, because for some reason the web server thinks this other random CSS file is there instead.  I've never seen an issue like this, it's definitely a head-scratcher.

I'm not aware of any caching mechanism being used on the web server.  But even then, why would some random CSS that I've never seen before be cached?

Comment: Check with your hosting company. Maybe something was up with them.

Comment: Your css include path is an absolute (notice the leading slash). Is this intentional?

Comment: I'd guess that this problem is specific to your situation. Contacting your hosting provider about locations of your files and folders is probably your best bet.

Comment: Which folder are you accessing through the FTP client? Do you have other domains hosted in the same server?

Comment: Good advice guys, I logged an issue and the host (MochaHost) apparently fixed it.  I'm gonna ask them what exactly the problem was, because now there's weird padding around the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar problem with JS not working... but when i moved it around on the server, as you demonstrate,  it did work.  Very frustrating problem which a week later resolved itself...

I discussed this with a programmer colleague and the only consensus we reached  that this was a hosting cache problem.

Ask your host to reset your cache, or eventually this problem should fix itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose that you have solved the problem on your end, but when I pull up your page now and View Source, I get perfectly acceptable looking CSS that begins with what you've said your real CSS file begins with.

It could be [have been?] a cache issue with your host, but if not I would suppose that it might be a local caching issue, instead. Not to insult your intelligence, but have you tried viewing it from a different browser or machine, or clearing your local cache?

Answer (score 0):

Good advice guys, I logged an issue and the host (MochaHost) apparently fixed it.  I'm gonna ask them what exactly the problem was, because now there's weird padding around the entire page.